# fabricjs clipTo is not working

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a simple script like:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(oImg) { 
        oImg.set({selectable:false})
        oImg.clipTo = function(ctx) {
            console.log("ctx")
            console.log(ctx)
        }
    })
```

Here `clipTo` function is not called. 
I want to clip `oImg` but `clipTo` is not called.

What is wrong in here ?

Comment: Put your `clipTo` function inside an `IFFE` and check?

Answer (score 0):

Gamer,

Here is working code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c1');
var src = "http://fabricjs.com/lib/pug.jpg";
canvas.backgroundColor = "#333";

var object;
fabric.util.loadImage(src, function (img) {
    object = new fabric.Image(img);
    object.set({
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        selectable: false,
        clipTo: function(ctx) {
            console.log("ctx")
            console.log(ctx);
            ctx.rect(
                        2,
                        2,
                        430,
                        430
                    );
        }
    });
    object.hasRotatingPoint = true;
    object.scaleX = object.scaleY = 0.25;
    canvas.add(object);
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Actually, your code working fine as well. I believe only difference only with library version. I used 1.7.1
My guess it didn't work for you, because your image wasn't active or not loaded yet into canvas, and you tried to clip it.

Also, i used **fabric.util.loadImage** instead of **fabric.Image.fromURL**

For *fabric.Image.fromURL* you should make an active object and then set properties. To make an active object you should do something like this:

```
var objImg = null;
var image = fabric.Image.fromURL(img, function(oImg) {
                    oImg.set({width: oImg.width,
                              height: oImg.height,
                              left: 100,
                              top: 100,
                              originX: 'center',
                              originY: 'center',
                              selectable: false,
                              perPixelTargetFind: true,
                              transparentCorners: false});

                    canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
                    objImg  = canvas.getActiveObject();
                    objImg.clipTo = function(ctx) {
                console.log("ctx")
                console.log(ctx);
                ctx.rect(
                            2,
                            2,
                            430,
                            430
                        );
            }
                    canvas.add(oImg);
});
```

Comment: You may want to take a moment and explain why this is working code. What was wrong with the original code, and how does this code resolve the problem? The idea of the site is to provide a learning experience, not just get something to copy and paste without thinking about it!