# How to use 'clipto' func in fabric.js 1.7 above

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I use fabric.js.
I use 'clipto' function to crop an image,
but it doesn't work in the version 1.7 above of the fabric.js.

When I include the version 1.6.7 or below, it works well.

https://jsfiddle.net/uemon/nqg2q2qs/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c',{ 
backgroundColor: '#ffffff', 
});

var imgURL = 'http://fabricjs.com/lib/pug.jpg';
var path = new fabric.Path('M121.32,0L44.58,0C36.67,0,29.5,3.22,24.31,8.41\
c-5.19,5.19-8.41,12.37-8.41,20.28c0,15.82,12.87,28.69,28.69,28.69c0,0,4.4,\
0,7.48,0C36.66,72.78,8.4,101.04,8.4,101.04C2.98,106.45,0,113.66,0,121.32\
c0,7.66,2.98,14.87,8.4,20.29l0,0c5.42,5.42,12.62,8.4,20.28,8.4c7.66,0,14.87\
-2.98,20.29-8.4c0,0,28.26-28.25,43.66-43.66c0,3.08,0,7.48,0,7.48c0,15.82,\
12.87,28.69,28.69,28.69c7.66,0,14.87-2.99,20.29-8.4c5.42-5.42,8.4-12.62,8.4\
-20.28l0-76.74c0-7.66-2.98-14.87-8.4-20.29C136.19,2.98,128.98,0,121.32,0z'); 

fabric.Image.fromURL(imgURL, function(image) {

   canvas.add(image);
   image.set({
            clipTo: function(ctx) {
                path.set({ 
                        left: -100, 
                        top: -100 
                    });
                path.render(ctx);
            }
   });
   canvas.renderAll();
});
```

But when I include the fabric.js of the version 1.7.0 or above, it doesn't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/uemon/affumnxh/1/

How can I use 'clipto' function in the ver.1.7 or above ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/42076133/7132835

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice !  I think there are another problem.  When I use 'ctx.rect()' instead of 'path.render(ctx)' in the 'clipTo' func, it works well. See, [link](https://jsfiddle.net/uemon/k3rowhL7/1/) . But I use 'path.render(ctx)' in the clipTo func, it draws only black area, like [link](https://jsfiddle.net/uemon/zdoua9e1/3/) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the problem by using 'objectCaching: false'.

See https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/3454

The final code is below.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c',{ 
  backgroundColor: '#ffffff', 
});

var imgURL = 'http://fabricjs.com/lib/pug.jpg';
var path = new fabric.Path('M121.32,0L44.58,0C36.67,0,29.5,3.22,24.31,8.41\
c-5.19,5.19-8.41,12.37-8.41,20.28c0,15.82,12.87,28.69,28.69,28.69c0,0,4.4,\
0,7.48,0C36.66,72.78,8.4,101.04,8.4,101.04C2.98,106.45,0,113.66,0,121.32\
c0,7.66,2.98,14.87,8.4,20.29l0,0c5.42,5.42,12.62,8.4,20.28,8.4c7.66,0,14.87\
-2.98,20.29-8.4c0,0,28.26-28.25,43.66-43.66c0,3.08,0,7.48,0,7.48c0,15.82,\
12.87,28.69,28.69,28.69c7.66,0,14.87-2.99,20.29-8.4c5.42-5.42,8.4-12.62,8.4\
-20.28l0-76.74c0-7.66-2.98-14.87-8.4-20.29C136.19,2.98,128.98,0,121.32,0z'); 


fabric.Image.fromURL(imgURL, function(image) {

   canvas.add(image);
   image.set({
            clipTo: function(ctx) {
                path.set({ 
                        left: -100, 
                        top: -100,
                        objectCaching: false
                    });
            path.render(ctx);
        }
   });
   canvas.renderAll();
});
```